# Caption in subfloat shifted to the right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, subfloats

I'm seeing strange behavior when using subfloat. I have 6 figures that I want to display as 2 by 3 (2 lines, 3 columns). The caption (a, b, c etc.) is shifted to the right which means figure b) is labeled a) and c) appears on page margin where no image is located.

```
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \centering
            \subfloat[Shield One]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figure/items/shield_1}}
            \subfloat[Shield Two]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figure/items/shield_2}}
            \subfloat[Shield Three]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figure/items/shield_3}}
            \newline
            \subfloat[Sword One]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figure/items/sword_1}}
            \subfloat[Sword Two]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figure/items/sword_2}}
            \subfloat[Sword Three]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figure/items/sword_3}}
            \caption[Items and their definition]{Items and their definition}
            \label{fig:items}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone have a clue ?

Comment: Newer use `\newline` inside a centered environment, i.e. `\centering` or `center` environment. Use \\ instead. (Since you did not give us a complete example document I cannot test if this will fix your problem.)

Comment: I had the exact same problem. In my case it was a clash with the caption package.

Comment: @KMAC The [`subfig` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf) mentions compatibility with [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption); even requiring it (see section **4.1 Caption package** of **4 Compatibility with other packages**, p 36). How did your usage clash with `caption`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check images and if there's sufficient space, also look for warnings. Perhaps post a compilable example. This compilable example shows the expected correct behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
        \subfloat[Shield One]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figure/items/shield_1}}
        \subfloat[Shield Two]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figure/items/shield_2}}
        \subfloat[Shield Three]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figure/items/shield_3}}
        \newline
        \subfloat[Sword One]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figure/items/sword_1}}
        \subfloat[Sword Two]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figure/items/sword_2}}
        \subfloat[Sword Three]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figure/items/sword_3}}
        \caption[Items and their definition]{Items and their definition}
        \label{fig:items}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: subfloats example]